Docusign Radio Button Captions are blank
In using the DocuSign REST API, I cannot figure out a way to make radio buttons have a caption.  I am setting the "caption" and "value" attributes.  The "value" attribute sets the tooltip when I hover over the button, but the button has no text.  What am I doing wrong?
"radioGroupTabs": [
    {
        "documentId": 66,
        "groupName": "bill",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "tabLabel": "bill",
        "radios": [
            {
                "pageNumber": 4,
                "xPosition": 125,
                "yPosition": 524,
                "value": "Radio1",
                "caption": "Radio1"
            },
            {
                "pageNumber": 4,
                "xPosition": 126,
                "yPosition": 544,
                "value": "Radio2",
                "caption": "Radio1"
            }
        ]
    }
]```


The caption property appears to be outdated and it's not possible to add text to the radio button unless it's added to the tooltip. I'd suggest using anchor strings to position the buttons next to text that's already in your document, or adding text tabs next to the buttons with your desired text.
